# unable to open .bat files for pan and carte for kettle 4.0.1 stable community version

Tags: kettle

Hhi all,

I'm using kettle4.0.1 communty version, here iam comfortable with spoon, but for running jobs and all i need to use pan and carte, my problem is other than spoon.bat niether of pan.bat nor carte.bat is opening. iam unable to run kitchen.bat also.. can someone suggest me with best solution

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in order to run jobs you will need to use `kitchen.bat` (unless you want to execute them remotely). Kitchen, Pan and Carte are command line tools, therefore you will need to specify your parameters also on the command line.
For example, you want to run a file called `job.kjb` located in `C:/jobs/` with a minimal log level. You would execute kitchen.bat from the commandline as follows

```
kitchen.bat -file=C:/jobs/job.kjb -level=minimal
```

Please see also more information here:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation